# if we use if(a>b>c) # a being greater than all three results in false

Tags: c

i executed this following code in C;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
        int a=15,b=10,c=5;
        if(a>b>c)
           printf("True");
        else
           printf("False");
        getch();
}
```

output:
False
Please explain me why?

Comment: (`a>b`) => 1, `1>c` is 0.

Comment: `if(a>b>c)` is the same as `if((a>b)>c)`, `a>b` is 0 or 1, which is always `< 5`.

Comment: That syntax is only valid in `Python` (that I know of), most other languages do not allow chained expressions like that.

Comment: @Cyber: Scheme allows this too ie `(< 2 3 4) => #t`

Comment: Mainly because `>` associativity is from left to right, thus `a>b` is evaluated first.

Comment: Don't use the C++ tag for questions about C, please. Tags are supposed to tell us what technologies are discussed/used in the question, not what technologies have similar looking names.

Answer (score 3):

There is no ternary (or 'chained') `>` operator in C or C++. Thus your expression evaluates to `((a>b)>c)` as evaluation is done left to right.

In C, true expressions evaluate to `1`, and false ones to `0`. In C++ my recollection is that they evaluate to boolean `true` or `false`, but then these type convert to `1` or `0` anyway, so the situation is much the same.

Using that principle, `a>b` will evaluate to `1` if `a>b` and to `0` otherwise. Therefore if `a>b`, the entire expression evaluates to `1>c`, else to `0>c`. As `c` is more than one, neither `1>c` nor `0>c` are true, and the output is always `0`, or false, and the program will print `False`.

To achieve what I strongly suspect you really want, use `((a>b) && (b>c))`.